# structure multiple select joins OOP Class

Tags: mysql, oop, join

Hello Since i'm lazy as hell i decided to create a class that calls every table and structures it to use in the following Class

```
    <?php
Class dbOperations
{
    public static function select($table, $what="*", $id="", $where=""){
        if(is_array($table)){
            $query = self::selectMore($table, $what, $id, $where);
        }else{
            $query = "SELECT ".$what." FROM ".$table;
            if(!empty($id))
                $query.= " WHERE ".$id.$where;
        }
        return $result = self::send($query);
    }
    public static function exists(){

    }
    public static function insert(){

    }
    public static function update(){

    }
    public static function delete(){

    }
    public static function send($query, $param =""){
        global $dbo;
        try{
            $stmt = $dbo->prepare($query);
            /*
            * Bind the parameter if an ID was passed
            */
            if ( !empty($param) ){
                $stmt->bindParam(":id", $param, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            }
            $stmt->execute();
            $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $stmt->closeCursor();
            return $results;
        }catch ( Exception $e ){
            die ( $e->getMessage() );
        }
    }
    public static function relationship(){
        //Só verifica se tem relacoes
    }
    public function selectMore($table, $select, $id="",$where){

        //SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id LEFT JOIN table3 ON table2.id=table3.id;
        $query = "SELECT ".$select;
        $select ="";
        $from ="";
        $fromAll ="";
        $whereJoin =" ON ";
        foreach($table as $key => $value){
            $whereCurJoin = $value->tname.".".$value->tid;
            //Aqui está um problema ao chamar esta funcao para 2 propósitos diferentes eles vão alterar a mesma var stati count
            $fromNow = cicleFunctions::todoCicle($table, " FROM ".$value->tname, " INNER JOIN ".$value->tname, "same");

            if(cicleFunctions::$count %2 == 1){
                $whereCurJoin.= " = ";

            }
            $fromAll .= $fromNow;
            $whereJoin .= $whereCurJoin;
            if(cicleFunctions::$count %2 == 0){
        $where =" WHERE ".$value->tname.".".$id ." = ".$where;
                $query .= $fromAll.$whereJoin.$where;
            }
        }
        var_dump($query);
        return $query;
    }
}
```

To call this class i use this

```
$result = dbOperations::select($DB->tables->produtos->tname, $DB->tables->produtos->columns->nome.", ".$DB->tables->produtos->columns->preco, $DB->tables->produtos->columns->preco, " >10");
```

this works fine even though i have to use enormous references just to place the name of which table i want`$DB->tables->produtos->tname`
my real question is in the method selectMore i want to allow myself to use multiple joins and so far i only managed to use 1 join that works fine I think my problem is struturing the array that this class should receive
And pls avoid talking about MVC i know what it is i'm just having fun thanks

Comment: I just decided to use extract to reduce the object to refer it, like this
extract((array)$DB);
extract((array)$tables);
$result = dbOperations::select($produtos->tname, $produtos->columns->nome.", ".$produtos->columns->preco, $produtos->columns->preco, " >10");
it's better this way

Answer (score 0):

I've come to a solution it's simpler if i ask the user first what are the tables he wants to join:

```
dbOperations::select($arraytable);
```

then ask how to join them:

```
dbOperations::join($arrayid);
```

and to finish send the query:

```
$result = dbOperations::send();
```

the method join:

```
public static function join($ids){
    foreach ($ids as $key => $value) {
        self::$ons[] = " ON ".$value;
    }
    self::$query .= self::$tables[0];
    for($i=1; $i<count(self::$tables); $i++ ){
        self::$query .= self::$tables[$i]. self::$ons[$i-1];
    }
}
```

What I did was 2 static properties both array one was for the tables the other for the id's to join
the Join method is going to add the id's to the array and then merge each value of array tables with the id's join which will give me this

> SELECT * FROM categorias INNER JOIN produtos ON categorias.id = produtos.id_categorias INNER JOIN prototipo ON categorias.id = prototipo.id

So far i can only do Inner joins since it's right in the class select i'll be working on that
Why not go right into an MVC because many of my friends use it and don't know what's behind it they don't even know they are calling a method or a class or what it is that's why i'm having all this trouble doing this hope you guys enjoy